# Creating a CategoricalDtype from an int column in Dask

Tags: dataframe, dask

dask.__version__ = 2.5.0

I have a table with columns containing many uint16 range 0,...,n & a bunch of lookup tables containing the mappings from these 'codes' to their 'categories'.

My question: Is there a way to make these integer columns 'categorical' without parsing the data or first replacing the codes with the categories.

Ideally I want Dask can keep the values as is and accept them as category codes and and accept the categories I tell Dask belong to these codes?

```
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'c01': np.random.choice(np.arange(3),size=10), 'v02': np.random.randn(10)})
dfd = dd.from_pandas(dfp, npartitions=2)
mdt = pd.CategoricalDtype(list('abc'), ordered=True)
dfd.c01 = dfd.c01.map_partitions(lambda s: pd.Categorical.from_codes(s, dtype=mdt), meta='category')
dfd.dtypes
```

The above does not work, the dtype is 'O' (it seem to have replaced the ints with strings)? I can subsequently do the following (which seems to do the trick):

```
dfd.c01 = dfd.c01.astype('category')
```

But than seems inefficient for big data sets.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Some context: I have a big dataset (>500M rows) with many columns containing a limited number of strings. The perfect usecase for dtype categorical. The data gets extracted from a Teradata DW using Parallel Transporter, meaning it produces a delimited UTF-8 file. To make this process faster, I categorize the data on the Teradata side and I just need to create the dtype category from the codes on the dask side of the fence.

Comment: Thanks for the question @Arnold, it's an interesting case that shouldn't be hard to support, but I also don't know currently how to do it.  I've asked Tom, the resident Pandas/Dask expert to take a look.  Hopefully he has time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have an upper bound on largest integer, which you call `n` (equal to 3), then the following will work.

```
In [33]: dfd.c01.astype('category').cat.set_categories(np.arange(len(mdt.categories))).cat.rename_categories(list(mdt.categories))
Out[33]:
Dask Series Structure:
npartitions=2
0    category[known]
5                ...
9                ...
Name: c01, dtype: category
Dask Name: cat, 10 tasks
```

Which is the following when computed

```
Out[34]:
0    b
1    b
2    c
3    c
4    a
5    c
6    a
7    a
8    a
9    a
Name: c01, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]
```

The basic idea is to make an intermediate Categorical whose categories are the codes (`0, 1, ... n`) and then move from those numerical categories to the actual one (`a, b, c`).

We have an open issue for making this nicer https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2829

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here TomAugspurger & MRocklin. FYI: Added a comment on https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2829